# Inactive input connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

On running this app on an emulator it is performing as expected but when run on an actual android device it is not producing desired result and is showing the warning "getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection" in the logs. It's a chatbot application where i'm performing get request on an api with retrofit2 library.

```
package com.example.chatbot;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView chatBotRV;
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private FloatingActionButton sendButton;
    private EditText queryText;
    private String USER_KEY = "USER";
    private String BOT_KEY = "CHAT_BOT";
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private APIservice apIservice;
    private ArrayList<ChatModel> chatModelArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chatBotRV = findViewById(R.id.chat_bot_rv);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        queryText = findViewById(R.id.chat_ev);
        chatModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!queryText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    String message = queryText.getText().toString();
                    queryText.setText(null);
                    getMessage(message);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your message :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(chatModelArrayList, MainActivity.this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        chatBotRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        chatBotRV.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    }

    private void getMessage(String msg){
        ChatModel chatModel_user = new ChatModel(msg, USER_KEY);
        chatModelArrayList.add(chatModel_user);
        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        String url = "MY_API_URL"+msg;
        String BASE_URL = "http://api.brainshop.ai/";
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        apIservice = retrofit.create(APIservice.class);
        Call<MessageModel> call = apIservice.getMessage(url);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MessageModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MessageModel> call, Response<MessageModel> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    MessageModel model = response.body();
                    chatModelArrayList.add(new ChatModel(model.getCnt(), BOT_KEY));
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some error on our side", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MessageModel> call, Throwable t) {
                chatModelArrayList.add(new ChatModel("Please revert your query", BOT_KEY));
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The InputConnection is overwhelmed by requests to clear the text. I tried modifying the code to check for text length before trying to clear it:

```
if (editText.length() > 0) {
  editText.setText(null);
}
```

This helps mitigate the problem in that pressing the send button rapidly no longer causes the stream of InputConnectionWrapper warnings. However, this is still prone to problems when the user rapidly pressing the send button when the app is under sufficient load, etc.

There's another way to clear text: Editable.clear(). with this I don't get warnings at all:

```
(like getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection)
```

try this:

```
if (editText.length() > 0) {
  editText.getText().clear();
}
```

Note that should you wish to clear all input state and not just the text (autotext, autocap, multitap, undo), you can use TextKeyListener.clear(Editable e).

```
if (editText.length() > 0) {
 TextKeyListener.clear(editText.getText());
}
```